# Which function is called when customer is deleted

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, delete

I want to know location of function when customer is deleted from:

1. Multiple customer selected and select delete action on "Manage Customer" page.
2. Delete single customer from "Edit Customer" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mass delete:

`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php` => `massDeleteAction()`

Delete single customer:

`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php` =>`deleteAction()`

Answer (score 0):

In `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php`

```
public function massDeleteAction()
{
    $customersIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer');
    if(!is_array($customersIds)) {
         Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Please select customer(s).'));
    } else {
        try {
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
            foreach ($customersIds as $customerId) {
                $customer->reset()
                    ->load($customerId)
                    ->delete();
            }
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Total of %d record(s) were deleted.', count($customersIds))
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
```